# Menu a:hover - Trying to get the background color in the whole bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm trying to put an a:hover over an menu that i created. If you could help me I really appreciate it! What im trying to achieve is to get the black in the whole bar. If you know what I mean.

Here is the menu: (The black is hover)
[image]

So here is my CSS for the menu:

```
#navigation {
padding: 5px;
height: 1em;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 12px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: -5px;
}

#navigation ul {
background-color: #fff;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: -5px;
}

#navigation li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
width: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.235), 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.047);
}

#navigation li ul {
padding: 5px;
display: none;
width: em;
background-color: #fff;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
background-color: #000;
padding:10px;
width: 300px;
color: #fff;
position:absolute;
}

#navigation a { 
color: #000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

#navigation a:link {    
color: #000;
}

#navigation a:hover {   
color: #fff;
background-color: #000;
}

#navigation a:visited { 
color: #000;
}
```

So if you need more information about this, just visit my Website where you can see the issue yourself. http://tomaswebdesign.com

Comment: Post the relevant HTML *here* in your question, otherwise it becomes, at best, useless (or most likely nonsensical) once the problem is resolved. Consider posting a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to experiment with, and see the code in action. Make it *easy* for us to *help* you.

Comment: The problem is now solved. I used the li:hover, a:hover code from David Thomas. But i had to remove the -webkit-transition. I can try to make a live demo of it. But I'm using weebly so there's no <li>LINK</li> in the HTML only {menu}. But I will try to make a demo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two options, the first is the simplest, simply add the `:hover` to the `li` itself:

```
li:hover,
a:hover  {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FYCuP/). For the above solution, I'd also suggest (as is included in the linked-demo) that you set `color: inherit` on the `a` element (*not* under `a:hover`)

The second is to style the `a` as a block element:

```
a {
    display: block; /* to fill the available horizontal space */
    height: 100%; /* to fill the available vertical space */
}
```

This does require that you remove the `padding` from the `li` element though, as that's what's 'forcing' the `background-color` away from the edge of the element, so:

```
li {
    padding: 0;
}

li a {
    padding: 10px; /* so that the padding is preserved, albeit
                      on the a element instead */
    display: block; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FYCuP/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#navigation li {
    display:block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.235), 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.047);
}
```

Or you can set anchor `width` and `height` to 100%.